# Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Charset was expected in kotlin

Tags: android, json, string, kotlin

I have the following code in my main activity:

```
var qNa_list = parseQuestions(loadJSONFromAsset("qna_list.json"))


fun loadJSONFromAsset(file_name:String): String? {
    var json: String? = null
    try {

        val isis = assets.open(file_name)

        val size = isis.available()

        val buffer = ByteArray(size)

        isis.read(buffer)

        isis.close()

        json = String(buffer, "UTF-8")


    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

    return json

}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error.

I fixed some other errors caused due to nullables, but this one is something I'm unable to decode.

Error:(127, 35) Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Charset was expected

I have changed some of the values to nullable to accomidate for the errors, but the `json = String(buffer, "UTF-8")` (UTF-8) is always underlined in red.

Comment: in java you can use byteArray.toString() directly, i don't know whether kotlin allows it lik that.

Comment: @Manojkumar I think you got it wrong. The end result needs to be a `Charset` object. Not a char. But a Charset like  "UTF-8"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This seems to have solved the issue.

It seems I need to specify the `Charset` type object and not a string like `UTF-8`.

1st method as mentioned by @Maroš Šeleng

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8")
```

Or, specify `Charset.UTF_8`

```
val charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8

json = String(buffer, charset)
```

Comment: Or you can use this `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Answer (score 4):

According to javadoc, `String` contructor accepts the second argument of type `Charset` [as seen here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) . You can use `Charset.forName(String)` static method to create your `Charset`.